# QEMU doesn't create a second serial port (Ubuntu x86-64 guest and host)

Tags: serial-port, virtual-machine, qemu

I run my QEMU version 3.0.0 by:
`x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2560 -hda img.qcow2 -serial pty -serial pty`

My host is an Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 and my guest is a fresh (i.e. default configuration) Ubuntu Server 18.04. Both are x86-64.

Upon starting, QEMU immediately prints:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -serial pty: char device redirected to /dev/pts/18 (label serial0)
qemu-system-x86_64: -serial pty: char device redirected to /dev/pts/19 (label serial1)
```

Also, the output of `info qtree` (in QEMU's monitor) is:

```
[...]
          dev: isa-serial, id ""
            index = 1 (0x1)
            iobase = 760 (0x2f8)
            irq = 3 (0x3)
            chardev = "serial1"
            wakeup = 0 (0x0)
            isa irq 3
          dev: isa-serial, id ""
            index = 0 (0x0)
            iobase = 1016 (0x3f8)
            irq = 4 (0x4)
            chardev = "serial0"
            wakeup = 0 (0x0)
            isa irq 4
[...]
```

So it seems that `serial0` and `serial1` should be quite the same.
According to [this site](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-10.html), `/dev/ttyS1` should be used for the serial port whose iobase is `0x2f8`, so from the output above I deduced that `serial1` should be used through `/dev/ttyS1`.

I can work without any issue with `/dev/ttyS0` in the guest and `/dev/pts/18` in the host.
However, I didn't manage to work with `/dev/ttyS1` in the guest, and it seems to me that `serial1` doesn't exist at all in the guest.

Inside the guest, the output of `dmesg | grep ttyS` (which should show the existing serial ports, according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125261/284477)):
`[    7.147289] 00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A`

What am I missing? Why does it seem like `serial1` doesn't exist inside the guest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my mistake.

Because the guest startup takes so much time (at least on my machine), I always immediately used `loadvm after_startup_snapshot`.

I now tried to let the guest go through startup, and the redirection of `/dev/ttyS1` worked perfectly.